# How to animate from point till destination point and then blink the drawn path?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a situation where i need to draw on 2D picture (such as networking diagram) from position to destination position like path, once the path is established then I need to blink that highlighted RED color path.

I tried as following which is not animated how do i animate the start and end instead of static draw as below:

```
$.tpt.prototype.setDraw = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('maincanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(100,20);

    // line 1
    context.lineTo(200, 160);
    // quadratic curve
    context.quadraticCurveTo(0, 200, 250, 120);
    // bezier curve
    context.bezierCurveTo(290, -40, 300, 200, 400, 150);
    // line 2
    context.lineTo(500, 90);

    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.strokeStyle = 'red';
    context.stroke();
};
```

Comment: for animating along the curves, I would make use of dash-array, but someones love maths :-)

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/ - do you mean this? if you mean that, then how can i do co-browsing drawing with animation? if its doable only with Javascript then it will be handy for co-browsing.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by co-browsing, and how it is related to your question, but yes, I was thinking of something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/1xcdLtv8/), which uses the same technique as the link you provided, but for canvas API. All you've got to find now is a way to programmatically have the length of your path, there are already some Q/A about in here, but I don't really have time to find it for you.

Comment: @Kaiido ... [See Documentation!](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html5-canvas/5281/navigating-along-a-path#t=201612081418450209939) :-)